# building GCC failed (/bin/sh gcc-4.9.2/config.sub gmp )

Tags: c, gcc, configure

I have the packages installed and in the parent directorty of gcc-4.9.2 and when I specify where the libs are such as --with-gmp it says:

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `gmp': machine `gmp' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh gcc-4.9.2/config.sub gmp failed
```

Command:

```
gcc-4.9.2/configure --with-gmp gmp  --enable-languages=c,c++
```

Comment: Use `--with-gmp=${ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_GMP}` instead. Variable can be defined that way: `ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_GMP=$(readlink -f gmp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use `--with-gmp` is `--with-gmp=the/path/to/gmp` note the `=` between and there should be no space.  What is happening is configure is treating `--with-gmp gmp` as two unrelated arguments and is treating `gmp` as the build, which is usually specified via `--build=your-build-target` but it seems if you just specify an argument without a `-` or `--` it treats it as the build option.